# SQL Server Reporting Services Running Total Over Aggregated Data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Everyone,
In SSRS, we have 2 columns as laid out below.

```
Sales  |  Running Sales
5.00   |      5.00
3.00   |      8.00
1.00   |      9.00
```

The distinction is that the first column (sales) is a is a grouping row and thus to get a Total for Sales per row, we are using =Sum(Fields!Sales.Value).

The problem occurs that when I try to use running value to get a running sales total. It gives me the SSRS error that  Aggregate functions can only be used on page headers and footers.  In this case it makes no sense to have the total in the footer.  Does anyone know a solution/workaround to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do and where you're having trouble. What is the data you have and what are you trying to get it to look like?

Comment: Apologize for not being clear.  What I have is the first column (Sales). I am trying to get the second column using Running value function but gives me the error that I described.

Comment: What's the running value formula you are using?

Comment: I have tried several.    =RunningValue(Fields!Sales.Value,Sum, Nothing) and =RunningValue(Fields!Sales.Value,Sum, "NameOfMyGrouping")

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Is the full error you are getting "Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers"? If so, are you perhaps referencing a report item and not a field?

Comment: @GeorgeEivaz What is the exact text of the error you are seeing? Aggregates can certainly be used in places other than the headers and footers.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; here is how I solved it.

So here is how to subtotal a column that is itself a sum function. SSRS 2005 wont allow you to aggregate an aggregate function. For example, the total of a column showing a Running Total, useful in daily stock balance calculations.
Add the following code to the report  Report > Properties

```
Dim public totalBalance As Decimal 
Public Function AddTotal(ByVal balance As Decimal) AS Decimal totalBalance = totalBalance + balance return balance 
End Function 
Public Function GetTotal() return totalBalance 
End Function
```

This code adds two variables: totalbalance and cnt as decimal numbers. And two functions `AddTotal` and `GetTotal`.
`AddTotal` allows items in rows to be added up, use as follows in a value cell, where you had;

```
=RunningTotal(Fields!ColumnName.Value,sum,nothing) 
with
=Code.AddTotal(RunningTotal(Fields!ColumnName.Value,sum,nothing))
```

in the total cell, where it you were unable to simply use

```
=sum(RunningTotal(Fields!ColumnName.Value,sum,nothing))
use instead
=Code.GetTotal()
```

Simply add more variables and public functions if you need to sum the sum of more that one field.

http://blog.wingateuk.com/2011/09/ssrs-aggregate-of-aggregate.html