# SSRS - Aggregate of an Aggregate

Tags: sql, reporting-services, aggregate

I am new to SSRS but have plenty of experience with Crystal Reports and am trying to do something that in Crystal is fairly simple but after hours of frustrating research it appears is very difficult in SSRS.

I have looked at these which bring me close:

[Running Total Over Aggregated Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312308/sql-server-reporting-services-running-total-over-aggregated-data/15965630#15965630?newreg=0e0f58e76eb14927b9f58a71eb5fe030)

[Aggregate Of Aggregate](http://blog.wingateuk.com/2011/09/ssrs-aggregate-of-aggregate.html)

I can semi-successfully obtain a group total but the group total resets to zero at the beginning of each page which isn't what I want.

I have two groups in my report the nested group has subtotals which are not totals of the detail data. How do I create Group Totals for the nested group subtotals? I have seen many people asking this question but so far have only been able to successfully create a Report total for the nested group subtotal. Can any one point me to a way to solve this?

It appears that this area is a regularly encountered problem that has no resolution. I see the same question raised here [SSRS Aggregating Aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954789/ssrs-aggregating-aggregates) also with no resolution. I was hoping it was just a knowledge issue on my part but it appears to be a structural issue with SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

OK So it sounds like you want to have a Subtotal and Grand total?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

In this example it is the typical sales company 
first line totals are easy, but the subtotal for the "daily group". Obviously you will have different groups/column names, but I think this is what you are looking for.

> Right-click the Order cell, point to Add Total, and click After.
>       This adds a new row containing sums of the quantity and dollar
>       amount for each day, and the label "Total" in the Order column. Type
>       the word Daily before the word Total in the same cell, so it reads
>       Daily Total. Select the Daily Total cell, the two Sum cells and the
>       empty cell between them. On the Format menu, click Background Color,
>       click Orange, and click OK.

Then for the grand total

> Right-click the Date cell, point to Add Total, and click After. This
>   adds a new row containing sums of the quantity and dollar amount for
>   the entire report, and the Total label in the Date column. Type the
>   word Grand before the word Total in the same cell, so it reads Grand
>   Total. Select the Grand Total cell, the two Sum cells and the empty
>   cells between them. On the Format menu, click Background Color, click
>   Light Blue, and click OK.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's the easy solution but unfortunately it is also the one that does not apply. 

First, I can't total the detail lines because that does not produce the result I need.  

Second, my first group subtotal is this: Max(Fields!FPOpeningBV.Value)

This means that when I right click, there's no option to add a total.

Does this make more sense? What I need is a way to calculate the total of "Max(Fields!FPOpeningBV.Value)" for each group.

Comment: OK that makes sense "Sum of MAX" = "Max"

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you to be a more specific? I am new to this so don't follow what you mean. When I first began I saw "=Sum(Fields!Additions.Value)" in another total field so thought this would work: "Sum(Max(Fields!FPOpeningBV.Value))" When I tried that I received an error so I tried Sum(Max(Fields!FPOpeningBV.Value), "GROUP1") but that kicked an error too. I have even tried naming the cell and referencing the cell name in the calculation but that also kicked out an error.

Comment: After much research it appears that this is a common question for which there does not appear to be an answer.

My question remains unanswered as does this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954789/ssrs-aggregating-aggregates?rq=1) and a few others I have read.